# "The security policy prevents the creation of a managed device because a custom OS is or has been installed on this device" on work profiles creation

Tags: samsung, work-profiles

I got the following message on a Samsung device when trying to create a work profile:

> The security policy prevents the creation of a managed device because a custom OS is or has been installed on this device

But the device is not rooted. I have installed the latest official Samsung ROM using Odin and also disable the bootloader.

How can I fix this?

Comment: AFAIK, this is related to [Knox being tripped](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250612/44325), and [there's no way to reset it](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/resetting-knox-trip.3751656/).